# Issue in Loading Obj Wave Front Model in iPhone

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I have taken [this sample](http://www.sendspace.pl/file/ecd348a3674ed1fe6eb10e5) of Obj Wavefront loader and replaced the model of 70 MB in size with polygons not triangles.

The model is available [here](http://www.sendspace.com/file/wl41cu); the issue is not loading the model.

Please help to solve the issue.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, and it looks like you're asking us to do all of your work for you. This forum is meant for asking for help with specific issues you run into while trying to solve your problem, not for others to solve your problems for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying what I think you are saying, you are trying to load 70MB of vertices to the iPhone? Try a smaller model, something like <1MB in size and see if the loading code works at all. 70MB is just too much for the iPhone to handle.

Comment: it works very fine with the other models of the same size but i'm confused why it responds in a wearied way.

Comment: I can understand that you are not a 3d model designer so it is probably a bother to you to downscale the model you are trying to load, but 70MB is like a million polygons. I can't see any use of that large of a model on an iphone screen if it weren't for scientific studies. but then also I would split the model into several pieces with different lods. I think your app falls apart because of too much memory consumption. btw, try ogre3d for iphone, it works great :)

Answer (score 0):

as far i observed this model loader supports only Blender models.. and iphone support triangulated 3D model..
you can check for confirmation..